# got error when building project: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I downloaded the following [project](https://github.com/mauriciomeirelles/FloripaBus) from github. When I tried to build it, it gave me the following error:

> ld: library not found for -lPods
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I noticed that pods folders is not present in xcode, but it should be there. I tried to copy and paste it into the project, and it still gave me this error. Can you tell me how I can resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install cocoapods: https://cocoapods.org
2. Run "pod install" in the project folder(where the Podfile located)
3. And open the project with the workspace file. (FloripaBus.xcworkspace)

This is because pods folders are added to .gitignore, and you should install the dependencies by yourself.